# can't make CSS word-wrap: break-word work

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have a problem where a wide form button will not wrap to the next line when the browser width is less than the button when displayed on one line.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SRD75/vqmo9ykg/4/)

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="" tabindex="26" value="Help me develop better solutions for small business" class="gform_button button" id="gform_submit_button_1">
```

CSS:

```
body {font-size: 16px;}
.gform_button.button {
  background-color: #E96E39;
  border-radius: 1em;
  -moz-border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  hyphens: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.046875em;
  padding: 0.84375em 0.875em 0.78125em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

How can I make the button wrap to the next line, and be at most 100% of the width of viewport?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this line of css to your input with the `button` class:

```
white-space: normal;
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 300px; // just to show the result
  font-size: 16px;
}

.gform_button.button {
  background-color: #E96E39;
  border-radius: 1em;
  -moz-border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  hyphens: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.046875em;
  padding: 0.84375em 0.875em 0.78125em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="" tabindex="26" value="Help me develop better solutions for small business" class="gform_button button" id="gform_submit_button_1">
```

Comment: Great. I accepted this as the answer, as I can't change the tag to `<button>`, and it is the simplest.

Comment: Thank you all, don't know why downvotes but both answers are correct. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It's an `<input>` tag, you can't make what you want, but you can change the tag to `<button>` and it works (you don't need the `word-wrap` because it's the default value):

https://jsfiddle.net/vqmo9ykg/8/

```css
body {font-size: 16px;}
.gform_button.button {
 background-color: #E96E39;
 border-radius: 1em;
 -moz-border-radius: 1em;
 -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
 hyphens: auto;
 box-sizing: content-box;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 700;
    max-width: 200px;
  letter-spacing: 0.046875em;
  padding: 0.84375em 0.875em 0.78125em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="gform_button button" id="gform_submit_button_1" tabindex="26" >Help me develop better solutions for small business</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Marcos. I am using Gravity Forms, so I can't change `<input>` to `<button>`.

Comment: Ok! No problem, this is the simplest CSS and the other answer is more CSS but the same HTML, so both are correct. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Set the width to 100% and the max-width to width of the button.